# encoding in java

Tags: java, encoding

i am using java application and i want to set encoding to UTF-8 using :

```
     request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

the problem is with the request it is not defined ?!

Comment: More code, please. The `request` variable is not defined? `setCharacterEncoding()` is not a method of your `request` object? What is `request`? Where did it come from? Your question is not answerable in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

This must be set prior to reading request parameters or reading input; therefore if you are doing it after the fact it will have no effect.

In addition if you are using Tomcat you should also set the URIEncoding to UTF-8 within your connectors as noted in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to specify the response encoding? That's done via the ServletResponse.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

> the problem is with the request it is not defined ?!

By the time your request arrives on the server, it is already encoded in a specific format. You cannot change the request message's encoding at runtime. However you can change the way the encoding is interpreted at runtime using the [serCharacterEncoding](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29)() method.

[More info on encoding.](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html)