# Java handling special character in request.getParameter

Tags: java, html, jsp, jakarta-ee, utf-8

I am trying to get parameter in my java class that contain a special character. I have added it as follows

```
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I have these two parameters:
(1)3 –days System Admin (6EE SP1) training at VMware Bangalore location
(2)Daiichi:eDossier â€“ Phase1 new_6500004691

After submitting the page i get the perfect result,but two parameter names gets change as below:

(1)Daiichi:eDossier Ã¢â¬â Phase1 new_6500004691
(1)3 âdays System Admin (6EE SP1) training at VMware Bangalore

Please suggest

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` before the first call to `getParameter()`.

If that doesn't work, have a look [at your Tomcat config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing).

Comment: `request.setCharacterEncoding()` won't work since it `Overrides the name of the character encoding used in the body of this request.` and not in parameters.

Comment: The documentation states: `This method must be called prior to reading request parameters or reading input using getReader(). Otherwise, it has no effect.` The parameters are part of the body ;-) http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: It's however not clear if the OP is talking about GET or POST parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I know what's your problem: Your application server/servlet container is not configured to support unicode characters.

You will have to configure you application server/servlet container to support UTF Encoding. Tomcat Example has been answered in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing).

Another alternative is to write a Character Encoding Filter and configure it in your web application.