# servlet request parameter character encoding

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I have a Java servlet that receives data from an upstream system via a HTTP GET request. This request includes a parameter named "text". If the upstream system sets this parameter to:

```
TEST3 please ignore:
```

It appears in the logs of the upstream system as:

```
00 54 00 45 00 53 00 54 00 33 00 20 00 70 00 6c   //TEST3 pl
00 65 00 61 00 73 00 65 00 20 00 69 00 67 00 6e   //ease ign
00 6f 00 72 00 65 00 3a                           //ore:
```

(The // comments do not actually appear in the logs)

In my servlet I read this parameter with:

```
String text = request.getParameter("text");
```

If I print the value of `text` to the console, it appears as:

```
T E S T 3  p l e a s e  i g n o r e :
```

If I inspect the value of `text` in the debugger, it appears as:

```
\u000T\u000E\u000S\u000T\u0003\u0000 \u000p\u000l\u000e\u000a\u000s\u000e\u0000 
\u000i\u000g\u000n\u000o\u000r\u000e\u000:
```

So it seems that there's a problem with the character encoding. The upstream system is supposed to use UTF-16. My guess is that the servlet is assuming UTF-8 and therefore is reading twice the number of characters it should be. For the message "TEST3 please ignore:" the first byte of each character is `00`. This is being interpreted as a space when read by the servlet, which explains the space that appears before each character when the message is logged by the servlet.

Obviously my goal is simply to get the message "TEST3 please ignore:" when I read the `text` request param. My guess is that I could achieve this by specifying the character encoding of the request parameter, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: GET parameters have to be ASCII or URL encoded, you can't use a special charset in there.

Comment: What is your web container? What is your html file charset?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing) might help.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares do you have a link for this claim?

Comment: Yup - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Current_standard

Answer (score 9):

Use like this

```
new String(req.getParameter("<my request value>").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8")
```

Comment: this solved my problem but i don't fully understand why... :(

Comment: [hidden edit] i dig a little deeper and find out that calling `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` was the only thing i needed (and it make much more sense)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use Filter for this

```
public class CustomCharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
                                                       throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
```

This should set encoding right for whole application

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was encoded with `UTF-16LE` (Little Endian) encoding, here is a class that successfully prints your string:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String hex = "00 54 00 45 00 53 00 54 00 33 00 20 00 70 00 6c"  +
                            "00 65 00 61 00 73 00 65 00 20 00 69 00 67 00 6e" +
                           "00 6f 00 72 00 65 00 3a"; // + " 00";
            System.out.println(new String(new BigInteger(hex.replaceAll(" ", ""), 16).toByteArray(), "UTF-16LE"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TEST3 please ignore?
```

Output with two zero's added to the input

```
TEST3 please ignore:
```

**UPDATE**

To get this working with your `Servlet` you can try:

```
  String value = request.getParameter("text");
  try {
      value = new String(value.getBytes(), "UTF-16LE");
  } catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {}
```

**UPDATE**

see the following [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16LE/encode.htm), it verifies that the hex produced is in fact `UTF-16LE`

Comment: The last character should be ':' rather than '?'.

Comment: @Don, that is because the last `00` is missing from `3a`, if you add it extra, it decodes correctly, either the encoder of that string is messed up or you maybe forgot to copy the last two zero's

Comment: you're right, probably a copy-paste error on my part. BTW are you sure this isn't big-endian? Thanks for your help

Comment: no problem, i'm not an expert with character encoding, but i'm pretty sure it is little endian, because big endian does not decode the string at all :)