# request.getParameter(String param) bug?

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

`getQueryString()`

gives

`cid=1&params=zDmrLGXJ1DboOuqBn2062Z%2BQmQ4w7ODNGAfZL4L8rpk%3D`.

and

`getParameter(PARAM_NAME)`

gives

```
zDmrLGXJ1DboOuqBn2062Z+QmQ4w7ODNGAfZL4L8rpk=
```

What happened with `%3D.` ?

I used `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")` to create *params*.

Comment: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: I get It. I have string that can contain & and = . What method can I use to encode it and decode before I put it in URL .The string is a message encrypted with AES.

Comment: see this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278900/httpservletrequest-setcharacterencoding-seems-to-do-nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%3D` is the equal (=) sign you have at the end of the parameter string. It's the same with `%2B` which was replaced by its decoded value: plus (+) sign.

Answer (score 1):

The `URLEncoder` coverts any [special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (@,=,+,etc.) so that it can be used as a url. `getParameter()` coverts the string back to what it was originally while `getQueryString()` returns the raw querystring.